# Metric evolving under Ricci flow with nonnegative scalar curvature is shrinking?

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, curvature, ricci-flow

Let  $g_{ij}(x,t)$  be a complete solution of the Ricci flow on a surface with bounded and nonnegative scalar curvature ,why the metric is shrinking ?